# Using same QTP script for 2 different environments

Tags: qtp

I wrote a script that points to my QA environment URL; it works great. I assume I can use the same script to point to my PROD environment URL simply by using parameterization.

I added an "Environment" column to the Data Table with two values; the URL for QA and the URL for PROD.

I started by adding a description property to each Page object (via Object Repository) and parameterize the "url". When I started this I quickly found this could take quite awhile and thought there might be a better way; is there?

In addition, I have close to 70 actions, each of which uses a "Page" and "Page 2" object. Hopefully, there is just one place where I can switch the URLs for these two objects: Is there?

Thanks for any helpful tips. This forum has been extremely helpful to me this entire week and I am grateful.

Comment: Hmm...should I just create 2 new user-defined environment variables, i.e. QA and PROD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need the URL in the `Page`s description, pages don't usually have any description whatsoever.

Wouldn't the same object repository work for production and testing environments depending on which is open? Just navigate to a parametrized URL at the beginning of the test and everything else should work.

Comment: You are exactly right. I simply opened a browser to my Prod environment and let the script run; and it ran. I just assumed I would need to tweak my script that was for my QA environment in some fashion. Turns out I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Any action / test can get a parameter, you can start the test by sending it an input parameter with the requested URL, and modify your object repository using `obj().SetTOProperty` function.